# I*m new to Laravel and I keep getting this error and not sure how to solve it

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm new to Laravel today and tried using

`php artisan make:auth`

to create a login.

It says it was successful and the login page was there, but when I clicked the link or typed in the registration link, I got the error in the image below:

[image: error for registration]

Comment: Does `metube` show up anywhere in your code? Did you add something called that?

Comment: metube is the name of the root folder that all of the laravel folders are in and isnt in the code itself. i have added a few classes, database tables and pages before adding the login if that has something to do with it but besides that i havent messed with anything

Answer (score -1):

If you are using XAMPP, make sure to place the project folder in htdocs.
composer works with php.exe selection.

Use artisan command : composer dump-autoload

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` is not an artisan command. It is related to `composer` and not with `artisan`.